# A noun adjunct / the possessive case

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, attributive-nouns

Sometimes it’s possible to use *either* a noun adjunct *or* the possessive case.

> **the shop door**
>   **the shop’s door**

However, in certain phrases it’s not OK to do so.

> the *ship’s crew* (the *ship crew* is **wrong**)

The questions are:

1. How can one find out what to use in such cases as “the shop(’s) door” when a noun adjunct option and the possessive case option are available?
2. How can one know which option is wrong in order to avoid the construction “ship crew”?
3. Is there a difference in meaning between (a) the shop door (b) the shop’s door?

Comment: "... in certain phrases it’s not OK to do so." -- Headlines do it all the time.

Answer (score 8):

These are nice and subtle questions.

Beginning with (3), there is a semantic difference between *shop door* and *shop’s door*.  If I tell you *I’ll wait by the shop door*, then I generally mean at the front of the store (or maybe by the door for deliveries), but not, for instance, at a door that separates the shop from the living quarters. The same goes for *shop window* (usually, not just any window in the shop, but the display window at the front) and *shop floor* (usually, not the floor out the back where goods are stored, but the parts accessible to the public). By contrast, *shop’s door/window/floor* can refer to more widely. For instance, *Today, I’m going to fix the shop’s floor* might well refer to parts out back; and in a related vein, the *shop’s side-window* is fine, the *shop side-window* is odd.

Hence, in answer to (1), you use the possessive for a more generic meaning, and the adjunct to pick out some more idiomatic, conventionally salient door of the shop, etc.

With regard to (2), I’m not sure that *ship crew* is, in fact, unacceptable. If, in a hotel, we’re trying to stop sailors and pilots from fraternising, I might tell you: *Put ship crews on the even floors and plane crews on the odd floors*. If there’s a fight, I might ask: *Was it a ship crew that started it?*  When *ship crew* becomes odd is when we have a specific, known ship in mind—in the same way that it’s odd to say *the dog owner*, rather than *the dog’s owner*, when the dog in question is known and salient.

Comment: "ship crew" is an utterly commonplace term, in aviation, sailing, really just generally. Variations like "cabin crew" are perhaps even more commonplace.  (This whole QA is a bit weird!)

Comment: Thanks Joe: I don't move in the right circles to know about boaty jargon.

Answer (score 0):

The situation couldn't be simpler.

"shop door" is a:  **type of door**.

That would be because, you know, shop is an adjective?  :)

Shop door, cheap door, expensive door, pink door, last door, aircraft door, submarine door, waterproof door ... shop door.

Adjective-noun.  Couldn't be simpler.

Whereas,

*the shop* ’s door is:  **the door of the shop you are referring to**.

---

shop door, pink door, cheap door:  **type of door**

Adjective.

---

John's door, the shop's door, the barn's door:  **doors belonging to John and others**

Possessive "S".

---

Again, couldn't be simpler.

Consider say "castle gate". That's the highly decorated, large, baroque, type of gate. (Note, **type** of gate.)

It would be completely normal to say:

"This castle's castle gate has gold accents, but this castle's castle gate is rusty."

You could also say:

"Here's the castle's castle gate - and over there is the castle's small gate, and over there is the castle's emergency gate."

One point of confusion: "shop door" (i.e. adjective-noun) is an extremely common term.  So when you say "The shop's door" it just, happens, to sound similar to that extremely common phrase.  No big mystery.

Comment: No, you're postulating a strict separation of usage that isn't correct. One would usually refer to the main gate of a castle (the extended feature) as the 'castle gate', not the 'castle's gate' If one were describing details of the actual wooden/iron elements of a particular gate / pair of gates, then the possessive _would_ be more natural.

Comment: EA, I'm sure that sounds right, but "castle gate" was merely an example of "type gate".  (Steel gate, security gate, fearsum gate, etc.)  I feel my answer (which is unimpressive and obvious) totally explains the three numbered questions in the question on this page.

Comment: I'd use 'shop door'  to refer to the door of a (usually specific) shop in certain circumstances, never to a 'shop-type door'. The attributive is here identifying, not classifying. Modifiers often have multiple roles (eg the adjective 'red' is identifying in 'please pass me the red book' but descriptive only in 'a large red book lay on the table'. 'Polar' is classifying in 'polar bear'.

Comment: {I don't care at all about specific examples, but, a "shop door" is very much a type of door!  (It's perhaps a bit archaic?)  Google a million "build a shop door!" type thing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3-nXWmBszg

Comment: Note too that "shop door" is used as a somewhat figurative term of art in retailing (meaning somethin glike "your company's face to the public") (rather like "shop floor" is used figuratively by, uh, uniionists and such) random example http://www.makearchitects.com/thinking/retail-innovation-beyond-the-shop-door-lessons-from-the-usa-part-2/

Comment: (lol of course there's a massive industry, who knew, around shop doors .. https://www.directindustry.com/industrial-manufacturer/shop-door-148080.html

Comment: There may be _some_ classifying usages, but internet examples of 'the shop door' well outnumber those for 'a shop door', and in both cases both are used overwhelmingly for 'the/a door of a shop' or for 'the entry of a shop' (eg these [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/kevindx092/at-the-shop-door/) illustrations). Not as a classifier (as with say 'French windows', 'Venetian blind', or 'flying buttress'). / Few would call 'shop' an adjective in 'shop door'. And in general, [modifier M] [head noun N] cannot be assumed to mean 'an M-type N'; there are ...

Comment: over a dozen semantic relations between M and N. An 'invalid toilet' is a toilet designed for invalids, not one that is invalid. A 'fake diamond' isn't even a diamond, and a 'heavy smoker' may well not be all that heavy.

Comment: That's all true, EA

Answer (score 0):

I guess my confusion comes when we use *Employee Details* and *Employee's Details*.

I would say: *Enter an employee name*, but I would say *Enter the employee's name*. The former being far more abstract, whilst the latter is very specific to the employee I have in mind.

Would it be wrong to say *Enter an employee's name*?

In my head I see *details* more like this:

*Employee Details* - an abstract idea that doesn't specify details about any particular employee. If anything, it highlights/emphasises the details element of the phrase.

*Employee's Details* - relates specifically to the details of one employee.

*Employees' Details* - relates specifically to the details of more than one employee. For example, this could be a group/department of employees within a business.

Would this be correct? What are the views?